# How to check user identity on my back-end server when user is logged in from an external service

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, server, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement authentication via Google/Facebook in my Android application, but I can't figure out how to verify if a request sent to my back-end server really come from an authenticated user.

I'll try to explain.
When I'm using a more classic way, like login/password, to authenticate users, I just need to check the credentials on the server side and return a token.
On the next requests, I simply add the token to it and my server can verify that the token is valid for the user who made the request.

When I'm using external login like Google or Facebook, the user is clearly authenticated on the client side by the  corresponding SDK, but my server doesn't have any information about this authentication : I don't have a token known by both sides.
If I call a service with just the user id returned by OAuth2 authentication, I don't have  security at all. Anybody can call my service with a random id and get some informations about my users.

I'm probably missing something simple in the process, but after searching for hours for a solution, I haven't found a good explanation.

If I add a service returning a token when registering the user id, anybody can call it and get a token, so this is not more secure...

I can add an app token to check that this is my app which is calling the service. This is a little more secure but anybody can reverse engineer my app to find the token...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I share what I've finally understood.

**Connection with login/password** :

1. The user enter his credentials
2. The credential are sent to the back-end server
3. The credentials are controlled on the server side
4. The server return an auth token
5. The auth token is passed with all request from the user
6. The server control the auth token for each request

**Connection with Google** :

1. The user authenticate via Google
2. The app is authorized to call Google API
3. The app request a token to Google
4. The Google token is sent to the back-end server
5. The server check the Google token validity (signature and content)
6. The server return an auth token
7. The auth token is passed with all request from the user
8. The server control the auth token for each request

source : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

**Connection with Facebook** :

1. The user authenticate via Facebook
2. The app get a token from Facebook
3. The Facebook token is sent to the back-end server
4. The server call Facebook API to check the Facebook token
5. The server return an auth token
6. The auth token is passed with all request from the user
7. The server control the auth token for each request

sources : [Provide secure Facebook authentication with my Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456829/provide-secure-facebook-authentication-with-my-server) , [Handling User Auth (via Facebook) and secure communication within an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725389/handling-user-auth-via-facebook-and-secure-communication-within-an-app)

I suppose it's possible to use the Google or Facebook token in each request but I think it's easier to have the same way to check the token in the future requests.

Answer (score 0):

When you use face-book for authentication it generates an authentication token. And if face-book has verified your user then how any invalid user will peep inside and get information about any user.

You follow this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3 tutorial its the best for implementing face-book login

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. If I'm right, when a user sign in with Facebook, I get an auth token in my app. So I can call Facebook API safely. That's ok. But what about my own services. My own server doesn't know the auth token returned by facebook. How can I use this token with my own services ?

Comment: when the user is signed in from face-book. You can take the name and other info about the user. And regarding your own server as soon as face-book validates it u do not have to do it. If sign in is successful u will get auth-token consider it for your server.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your response, I've understood it during the night :) When I get the auth token from Google or Facebook, I send it to my own server and the server call Google or Facebook API to validate the token. I didn't realize that I need to call Google or Facebook from my back-end server in the first time.